# Perl: Read web text file and "open" it

Tags: perl, http, file-io, while-loop

I'm trying to create a script that will read text files and then analyse them, regardless of whether the text file is online or offline.

The offline part is done, using

```
open(FILENAME, "anyfilename.txt")
analyze_file();

sub analyze_file {
   while (<FILENAME>) {analyze analyze}
}
```

Now for the online part, is there anyway to read a text file on a website and then "open" it?

What I hope to achieve is this:

```
if ($offline) {
   open(FILENAME, "anyfilename.txt")
}
elsif ($online) {
   ##somehow open the http web text so that I can do a while (<FILENAME>) later
}

analyze_file();

sub analyze_file {
   while (<FILENAME>) {analyze analyze}
}
```

There's the "get('http://weblink.com/textfile.txt;)" but it creates a string. I can't do a while () with that string.

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's simple, just use the [`open FILEHANDLE,MODE,REFERENCE`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) style of [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

```
use LWP::Simple;
if ($offline) {
   open( FILENAME, '<', "anyfilename.txt" )
}
elsif ($online) {
   my $text = get 'http://example.com';
   open( FILENAME, '<', \$text );
}
```

Comment: +1, this is probably the right way to do it. But depending on the occasion, opening a file handle to a scalar seems to much for me and I'd just use my proposed solution of splitting the scalar into an array of lines.

Comment: @sidyll Why would opening a file handle to a scalar be too much?

BradGilbert Thank you!!

Comment: @Brad-Gilbert What does the slash actually do in this context of \$? Normally if nullifies whatever comes after it. Why does the code work because the $ in text is nullified?

Comment: We also talk about this quite a bit in _Effective Perl Programming_. It's a great trick that saves a lot of coding and hassle.

Comment: @JohnTan I don't know what you mean by `\` nullifying whatever comes after it.

Comment: @BradGilbert What I was trying to say was "$" usually means that the words behind it refer to a variable. eg $name_of_the_variable means name_of_variable is the name of a variable.

So, what does "\$" do?