# Perl Get the web content then writing it as a text file

Tags: perl

I'm trying to create a script which get from the website a log file(content) then inputting it to a text file, but I am having errors if use strict is present:

Can't use string ("/home/User/Downloads/text") as a symbol ref while "strict refs" in use at ./scriptname line 92.

Also by removing the use strict: I get another error which is:

File name too long at ./scriptname line 91.

I tried the [Perl: Read web text file and "open" it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618524/perl-read-web-text-file-and-open-it)

But, it did not work for me. Plus I am a newbie at Perl and confuse of the Perl syntax.

Are there any suggestions or advices available?

Note: The code does it greps the entire line with the RoomOutProcessTT present and display it together with how many times it appears.

Here is the code.

```
my $FOutput = get "http://website/Logs/Log_number.ini";
my $FInput = "/home/User/Downloads/text";
open $FInput, '<', $FOutput or die "could not open $FInput: $!";
my $ctr;
my @results;
my @words = <$FInput>;
@results = grep /RoomOutProcessTT/, @words;
print "@results\n";
close $FInput;

open $FInput, '<', $FOutput or die "could not open $FInput: $!";
while(<$FInput>){
    $ctr = grep /RoomOutProcessTT/, split ' ' , $_;             
    $ctr += $ctr; 
}   
print "RoomOutProcessTT Count: $ctr\n";
close $FInput;
```

Comment: the first argument to `open` is the name of the filehandle, not the file name itself. the `<` means to open the filename specified _after_ it as READ, and use the filehandle name to reference it. Your usage of `open` is incorrect. See [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Comment: You mean that I should create another variable for the filehandler? I also done that but it produces another error which is "could not open GLOB(0x17252b0): File name too long at ./scriptname line 92." I am at lost.

Comment: It's not a variable per-se, it's a bareword identifier that you use to interact with the file you've opened, whether for reading or writing. See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to open is the filehandle name, not the actual name of the file. That comes later in the `open` function.

Change your code to:

```
my $FOutput = get "http://website/Logs/Log_number.ini"; # your content should be stored in this 
                                                        # variable, you need to write data to your output file.
my $FInput = "/home/User/Downloads/text";
open OUTPUT_FILEHANDLE, '>', $FInput or die "could not open $FInput: $!"; # give a name to the file 
                                                                          # handle, then supply the file name itself after the mode specifier. 
                                                                          # You want to WRITE data to this file, open it with '>'
my $ctr;
my @results;
my @words = split(/(\r|\n)/, $FOutput); # create an array of words from the content from the logfile
                                        # I'm not 100% sure this will work, but the intent is to show
                                        # an array of 'lines' corresponding to the data

# here, you want to print the results of your grep to the output file
@results = grep /RoomOutProcessTT/, @words;
print OUTPUT_FILEHANDLE "@results\n"; # print to your output file
# close the output file here, since you re-open it in the next few lines.
close OUTPUT_FILEHANDLE;

# not sure why you're re-opening the file here... but that's up to your design I suppose
open INPUT_FILEHANDLE, '<', $FInput or die "could not open $FInput: $!"; # open it for read
while(<INPUT_FILEHANDLE>){
    $ctr = grep /RoomOutProcessTT/, split ' ' , $_;             
    $ctr += $ctr; 
}   
print "RoomOutProcessTT Count: $ctr\n"; # print to stdout
close INPUT_FILEHANDLE;  # close your file handle
```

I might suggest switching the terms you use to identify "input and output", as it's somewhat confusing. The input in this case is actually the file you pull from the web, output being your text file. At least that's how I interpret it. You may want to address that in your final design.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, as you said I think I am producing an output, I was using the file handler wrong... And also will use your example as reference. Will test and then tweak the code for a while

Comment: @galbert well, since this no longer really has to do with the original question, I think I can only go as far as to guide you in the direction you need... How many results do you expect from the remote location file? Are you sure your algorithm is correct? How "huge" is huge? Think about a little more debugging and it should get you where you need to be. Good luck.

Comment: Your guide was indeed helpful Ryan J. As long as there is an existing text named RoomOutProcessTT in there... Yeah I think so because, I created, divide and conquer each script that's why I can say that my algo is correct... It is ok now but, my problem now is that the content is being outputted and I don't want that still searching for a way to do that...